# Google Sheets API Macro to Protect Cells not Containing String

Tags: performance, google-apps-script, optimization, google-sheets-api

I have a macro to add a protection to every cell in a range that does not contain a certain string. This macro does add protections, but it exceeds the maximum execution time before it can add protections to all the desired cells in the range. By my reckoning, it will need to be around x100 times more efficient to complete the task in the allowed execution time. I have recently learned about making Sheets API requests and using the batchUpdate method to massively improve performance ([prev. post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77816692/google-sheets-macro-to-remove-protections-from-range-exceeded-maximum-execution)). Wanting to utilize this, I have tried adapting my existing macro to use API requests, but the requests fail. It gives the error message

> "GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to sheets.spreadsheets.batchUpdate failed with error: The service is currently unavailable."

[update] Error given even when the range is only a few cells:

> GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to sheets.spreadsheets.batchUpdate failed with error: Invalid value at 'requests[0].add_protected_range.protected_range.range.sheet_id' (TYPE_INT32)

I am unsure if this is because the requests I am making are bad or if the way requests are sent is incorrect.
How can I fix my requests to complete the API batchUpdate, or otherwise drastically improve the performance of adding cell protections?

Here is the macro script [updated]:

```
function addProtectionsToCells() {
  // Replace 'YOUR_SPREADSHEET_ID', 'YOUR_SHEET_NAME', and 'A1:C10' with your actual values
  var spreadsheetId = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId();
  var sheetName = 'example';
  var rangeToProtect = 'J2:W2';
  var stRow = range.getRow()
  var enRow = stRow +1
  var stCol = range.getColumn()
  var enCol = stCol + 1

  // Replace with your specific strings
  var stringsToProtect = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'y', 'æ', 'c', 'g', 'ā', 'ē', 'ī', 'ō', 'ū', 'ȳ', 'ǣ', 'ċ', 'ġ'];

  // Get the current sheet
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var range = sheet.getRange(rangeToProtect);
  var values = range.getValues();

  // Initialize the batchUpdate request
  var requests = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < values[i].length; j++) {
      if (!stringsToProtect.includes(values[i][j])) {
        // Create protection request
        var protectionRequest = {
          addProtectedRange: {
            protectedRange: {
              range: {
                sheetId: spreadsheetId,
                startRowIndex: i + stRow,
                endRowIndex: i + enRow,
                startColumnIndex: j + stCol,
                endColumnIndex: j + enCol,
              },
              warningOnly: false,
              editors: {
                domainUsersCanEdit: false,
                users: []
              }
            }
          }
        };

        // Add protection request to the batchUpdate requests
        requests.push(protectionRequest);
      }
    }
  }

  // Execute the batchUpdate request
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({ requests: requests }, spreadsheetId);
}
```

And here is a copy of the sheet being worked in, with only relevant cells remaining. Both the ranges J2:W2793 (<40k cells) and AF2:EJ2793 (>300k cells) will need to have all other cells locked.

[Protections Example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10vK_fJ_XZik_A10CuNioUBFMpOeNEOphd4TjIFuYm8o/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: When does the error throw up? Immediately or after sometime?

Comment: You should remove all of the function calls from the loop especially considering they always return the same number;

Comment: Although I think that your request body is required to be modified, I'm worried that from `GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to sheets.spreadsheets.batchUpdate failed with error: The service is currently unavailable.` and `Both the ranges J2:W2793 (<40k cells) and AF2:EJ2793 (>300k cells) will need to have all other cells locked.` the reason for your current issue might be due to large size of Spreadsheet. In my experience, when a large Spreadsheet is used, such an error occurs. In this case, how about separating the requests by the range?

Comment: By the way, in your situation, do you want to add the protected ranges to your current Spreadsheet? Or, do you want to remove all protected ranges and add new protected ranges? Because in the current stage, the same cells can be protected multiple times by script. I think that this is an important point.

Comment: @ TheMaster it gives the error after about 1 minute.

@ Tanaike, I could break it up, just with my current functioning macro it would take several hours to lock all the cells. And whoops, ya I should have removed the protections in the linked sheet. I will change that now.
@ Cooper, ok thanks, I will try and do that.

Comment: @pancake You can only ping one user per comment. You should make new comments for addressing each user, otherwise they won't be notified.

Comment: @Cooper I replaced the calls in the loop with variables set before the loop. Hopefully that'll give it a good boost, thanks.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Now I noticed your reply. I apologize for my late reply. From your reply, I understood that in your situation, the initial spreadsheet has no protected cells. When I saw your sample Spreadsheet, I noticed that the number of protected cells in "J2:W2793" is more than 9000. And, in your question, you say `And here is a copy of the sheet being worked in, with only relevant cells remaining. Both the ranges J2:W2793 (<40k cells) and AF2:EJ2793 (>300k cells) will need to have all other cells locked.`.

Comment: I think that in this case, even when the protected cells are set by splitting the number of cells, the process cost will be very high. I'm worried about this. For example, can you split the rows by several Spreadsheets? When you can reduce the number of cells, the process cost can be reduced. But, if this was not your expected direction, I apologize.

Comment: @Tanaike, when I saw your comment I went & changed the spreadsheet linked here to another one in which I removed the already protected cells before I pinged you again. Now you will find no cells protected. Yes, the number of cells to be protected is quite large. Good idea, splitting it up into multiple spreadsheets would help a lot. Another improvement that could be made with some effort is to reduce the number of ranges to be protected (by about ½) by adding the last several columns of empty cells as one range to be protected each. But first I need the macro to work & apply protections at all

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `Another improvement that could be made with some effort is to reduce the number of ranges to be protected (by about ½) by adding the last several columns of empty cells as one range to be protected each.`, even when the number of protected cells is about 4500, the process cost is high. So, in this case, I would like to recommend splitting the rows into multiple Spreadsheets.

Comment: @Tanaike, Thanks, it is good to know a ball park number for about how many cells could be protected at once. I think you are right, I will probably need to split the data into multiple spreadsheets. Do you think the sheer number of protection requests is what is making my current script fail? I still have not been able to get it to work at all. Do you spot any errors in the code?

Comment: UPDATE: I just thought to run the script with a reduced range after thinking about what Tanaike had said and it gives me this error:
GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to sheets.spreadsheets.batchUpdate failed with error: Invalid value at 'requests[0].add_protected_range.protected_range.range.sheet_id' (TYPE_INT32)

Comment: Thank you for replying. I think that your request body is required to be modified. But, about `Do you think the sheer number of protection requests is what is making my current script fail?`, I think that the reason for the error of `"GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to sheets.spreadsheets.batchUpdate failed with error: The service is currently unavailable."` is due to this.

Comment: About your new error of `GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to sheets.spreadsheets.batchUpdate failed with error: Invalid value at 'requests[0].add_protected_range.protected_range.range.sheet_id`, unfortunately, I cannot know your current situation. So, I have no clear answer. I think that this is due to my poor skill. I apologize for my poor skill. Can you provide a sample Spreadsheet including your current script for correctly replicating your current issue?

Comment: @Tanaike I have now updated the code in this post with the current script, and the example sheet is still linked at the bottom. I have been messing around with it for a while trying to get it to work, but I haven't been able to figure it out. Thanks for helping

Comment: Thank you for replying. First, if you cannot understand my English, please tell me. I proposed to split the rows into multiple Spreadsheets to avoid high process costs. I thought that you understood it. But, when I saw your updated Spreadsheet, it seemed that the rows were not split. You want to achieve your goal by keeping 2798 rows. Is my understanding correct? I would like to correctly understand your current goal.

Comment: @Tanaike ah sorry, I did not realize you were wanting the example to have the rows split. My current goal is to get the script to function at all. I updated the range for the script to run on J2:W2 (= 14 cells), which will not be too much for the API batchupdate request, but that gives the previously mentioned error. If you run the updated script from the post on the example spreadsheet though, it ought to give the error you were wanting to investigate.

Comment: as a side note as I have learned more about Sheets Apps Script & the sheets API, I have gotten better at googling questions and found this post which might help. If I'm understanding it correctly, it is possible to have a range unprotected by first protecting the whole sheet then listing ranges to be subracted from that. I will have a look at this more in the next couple days. Thanks again
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38993561/protect-ranges-with-google-apps-script

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill again. From your updated script and spreadsheet, I noticed that you misunderstood my comments. In your current situation, there are a lot of rows in the target sheet of Google Spreadsheet. And, in order to achieve your goal, it is required to protect over 9000 cells.

Comment: In this case, the process cost becomes high, and this is the reason for your issue of `the service is currently unavailable.`. From this situation, I proposed to split rows into multiple Spreadsheets. In this case, for example, rows from 1 to 500 are put into Spreadsheet "A". Rows from 501 to 1000 are put into Spreadsheet "B", and so on.

Comment: When I saw your updated Spreadsheet, it seemed that 2798 rows existed. I think that in this case, even when the rows are split, the process cost becomes high when the number of protected cells is large. Even when unprotected ranges are used, it seems that the number of unprotected ranges is about 9000. In this case, the process cost also becomes high. So, I proposed the above approach for reducing the number of protected cells in one Spreadsheet with the above approach. If you cannot understand my comments, please tell me.