Script to Unprotect All Protected Ranges
I wrote an Apps Script file to protect cells on-edit, and it was working for a while, but it stopped working recently. I suspect I hit some sort of cap on the number of protected ranges one sheet can have. I'd rather not delete thousands of protected ranges manually, so I'm trying to write a script that will remove all protections automatically when run.
I visited the Class Protection page of the Apps Script documentation site. It recommended a script to do exactly what I need, but that script times out and throws an error when run. The code is below:
function removeProtections() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var protections = ss.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE);
  for (var i = 0; i < protections.length; i++) {
    var protection = protections[i];
    if (protection.canEdit()) {
      protection.remove();
    }
  }
}

In the execution log, I see two messages: First, a notice message saying "Execution started." Second, after the execution runs for a while, I get an error message saying "Exceeded maximum execution time."

I guessed that this thread might be an answer to your question. https://stackoverflow.com/q/77816692

It says in the documentation that the remove function can be ran on a range or a sheet. Maybe by looping on the sheets and removing every protection in once would enhance the performance?
function myFunction() {
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
const sheets = ss.getSheets();
let protections;
for (let i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
    protections = sheets[i].getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE)[0];
    if (protections && protections.canEdit()) {
        protections.remove()
    }
}

}
The other approach would be to set a timer on the function, like stopping the execution after 20 min for example and storing the current index in script properties, example here
